# Converting two columns table into one column table in Google Sheets

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, transpose, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

In column A there is a list of tasks.

In column B each task has an associated group.

How to, using built-in formulas, generate sequence like in column D?

Here is a screenshot :

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(QUERY(IF(A2:B="",,A2:B&"♦"), 
 "select max(Col1) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 pivot Col2", 0)
 ,,999^99)),,999^99), "♦"))))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: we gotta get you using FLATTEN()! :)

Answer (score 1):

This should work as well as player0s.  I keep trying to get him to use FLATTEN() :)

```
=QUERY(FLATTEN(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(A2:B,"select Max(A) group by A pivot B"))),"where Col1<>''")
```